# GTM-OAuth 2.0 multiple post data parameters?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oauth-2.0, google-toolbox-for-mac

Simple one here.
In GTM-OAuth 2.0 how do I send multiple post parameters?
Here is how I post data now:

```
        NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"i=%@",articleIndex];
        [myFetcher setPostData:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

My question is how to send multiple parameters like i=1&t=2? is it like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a different format string, like

```
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"i=%d&t=%d", i, t];
```

Another common technique is to put parameters pairs as strings like `@"i=1"` into an NSArray, and use NSArray's joining method, `[array componentsJoinedByString:@"&"]`, to make the full string.

Comment: Then why this                `NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"i=%@&ac=edit&a=user/-/state/com.google/read", item];`
 doesn't work? It shows me error 400.